# Comunicação Serial com Balança de Precisão

Tags: java, serial

estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação para medir o fluxo de solda que passa pela placa numa linha de produção, mas estou tendo um pouco de dificuldade na hora de conectar a balança de precisão com o PC via porta serial. Estou usando a linguagem JAVA e a api javax.comm, se alguém puder me ajudar ou se souber outra maneira de fazer essa comunicação, me ajudem!!!

Comment: O seu problema é com o Java ou com a balança em si? Ela deve ter um software que você consegue usá-la sem a necessidade de desenvolver seu próprio sistema, não? Caso sim, primeiro tente usá-la através dele, pois pode ser falta de driver ou coisa do tipo. E quando chegar na parte da programação, precisará colocar mais detalhes para saber o que já foi feito e onde pode estar o erro.

Answer (score 1):

Bom eu trabalho muito com serial aqui e vou te passar algumas dicas a API javax.comm ela está bem deefasada, recomendo usar o java rxtx (não é dificil encontrar), para ela funcionar tem que usar seus respectivor DLL's de acordo com o o Java instalado (SO x64 e Java x86, DLL x86), aqui vai alguns exemplos de codigos:

```
import gnu.io.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class serial{
    public SerialPort serialPort;
    private OutputStream outStream;
    private InputStream inStream;

/**
 * Get the serial ports available
 * @return The existing ports
 */
public String[] getPortas (){
    ArrayList<String> portas = new ArrayList<String>();
    //System.out.println(java.library.path);
    CommPortIdentifier serialPortId;
    //static CommPortIdentifier sSerialPortId;
    Enumeration<?> enumComm;
    //SerialPort serialPort;
    enumComm = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifiers();
    while (enumComm.hasMoreElements()) {
        serialPortId = (CommPortIdentifier) enumComm.nextElement();
        if(serialPortId.getPortType() == CommPortIdentifier.PORT_SERIAL) {
            portas.add(serialPortId.getName());
        }
    }
    return portas.toArray(new String[portas.size()]);
}

/**
 * Connect to the given port
 *
 * @param portName The name from the port to be connected
 * @throws NoSuchPortException
 * @throws PortInUseException
 * @throws IOException
 */
public void connect(String portName) throws NoSuchPortException, PortInUseException, IOException {
        // Obtain a CommPortIdentifier object for the port you want to open
        CommPortIdentifier portId =
                CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifier(portName);

        // Get the port's ownership
        serialPort =
                (SerialPort) portId.open("Demo application", 5000);

        // Set the parameters of the connection.
        setSerialPortParameters();

        // Open the input and output streams for the connection. If they won't
        // open, close the port before throwing an exception.
        outStream = serialPort.getOutputStream();
        inStream = serialPort.getInputStream();

        serialPort.notifyOnDataAvailable(true);
}

public InputStream getSerialInputStream() {
    return inStream;
}

public OutputStream getSerialOutputStream() {
    return outStream;
}

private void setSerialPortParameters() throws IOException {
    int baudRate = 9600; // 19200bps
    try {
        // Set serial port to 19200bps-8N1
        serialPort.setSerialPortParams(
                baudRate,
                SerialPort.DATABITS_8,
                SerialPort.STOPBITS_1,
                SerialPort.PARITY_NONE);

        serialPort.setFlowControlMode(
                SerialPort.FLOWCONTROL_NONE);
    } catch (UnsupportedCommOperationException ex) {
        throw new IOException("Unsupported serial port parameter");
    }
}


public void disconnect() {
    if (serialPort != null) {
        try {
            outStream.close();
            inStream.close();
            serialPort.notifyOnDataAvailable(false);
            serialPort.removeEventListener();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            // don't care
        }
        // Close the port.
        serialPort.close();
    }
}

public void enviaString (String b) throws IOException{
    enviaBytes(b.getBytes());
}


public void enviaBytes (byte[] b){
    try {
        outStream.write(b);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Com essa classe é possivel enviar e receber dados da Serial, na classe principal é necessario conectar a alguma porta (as portas disponíveis podem ser vistas com o metodo getPortas na classe acima), e e criar o listener para receber os dados.

```
serial porta = new serial();
porta.connect(n);
porta.serialPort.addEventListener(new SerialPortEventListener() {

                                @Override
                                public void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent arg0) {
                                    switch (arg0.getEventType()) {
                                    case SerialPortEvent.DATA_AVAILABLE:
                                        leSerial();
                                        break;
                                    }
                                }
                            });

private void leSerial() {
    InputStream inStream = porta.getSerialInputStream();
    try {
        int availableBytes = inStream.available();
        byte dadosRecebidos[] = new byte[availableBytes];
        if (availableBytes > 0) {
            // Read the serial port
            inStream.read(dadosRecebidos, 0, availableBytes);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {

    }
}
```

e para enviar dados utilize o os metodos da classe serial enviaString e enviaBytes.